# why does this variable not change?

Tags: javascript

in this piece of code:

```
function change(s)
{
  var number = s.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  for(var i = 0; i < number.length ; i++)
  {
    console.log(number[i]); //Line1
    number[i] = '1';
    console.log(number[i]); //Line2
  }
}
```

the results of Line1 and Line2 are both the same(they return "2") ! what is going on here?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. You can't change them so this line does nothing

```
number[i] = '1';
```

Comment: @GolezTrol [Strict Mode](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/) will do that for you. See the "Errors for Immutables" section.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read an string as an array. Char by char. Looks like JS doesn't allow altering value of any index in such case. If you do something like: number = "12345", value at index: (I) will change. That won't solve your purpose though. To do what you are trying to do, you should split the number and then iterate and change.

An example:

```
function change(s) {
    var number = s.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var sArr = number.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length ; i++) {
    console.log(sArr[i]); //Line1 (prints original)
    sArr[i] = i;
    console.log(sArr[i]); //Line2 (prints changed)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell completely what you want from this, but I think this will do it?

```
function change(s)
{
    var number = s.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var newstring = number;
    for(var i = 0; i < number.length ; i++)
    {
        console.log(number[i]); //Line1
        newstring[i] = '1';
        console.log(number[i]); //Line2
    }
    return(newstring); //or something to that effect
}
```

Now, this is actually kind of pointless code, I assume you're going to be replacing '1' with something a bit more useful.